# Laravel - Multiple User Types with different Login Credentials

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I currently can't pinpoint which solution is best in the following situation.

I need 2 different accounts namely: Customer and Admin.

However, both account types have different login Credentials i.e.
Admin logs in using email and password.
Customer logs in using username and customerCode.

I am currently using Laravel 8 with Jetstream.

I also created separate user models which both inherit Users Model, which is created automatically by JetStream

Is there a way where I can use different log in credentials for 2 different account types please? If so, what's the best way to go about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just create 2 different login form

Comment: Spatie roles and permissions

Answer (score 0):

Set up different auth guards, e.g. `users` and `admin`. This way, you can have separate login

https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#adding-custom-guards

You can specify which guard to use for relevant parts of your application. This could be done using route middleware, and you can set a default in `config/auth.php`

e.g.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::shouldUse('admin');

// or

Auth::guard('admin')->login(...);

// or

Auth::guard('users')->attempt($request->only('username', 'customer_code'));
Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));
```

Comment: Where should the following code be placed please?

Comment: stack overflow is not to guide you through the solution, but rather to answer a question or point you in the right direction. this medium article might help with a more hands on solution: https://medium.com/@sagarmaheshwary31/laravel-multiple-guards-authentication-setup-and-login-2761564da986

Answer (score 0):

You can extend FortifyServiceProvider class and in boot method define your logic based on user role. This is a simple example.

```
public function boot()
    {
        // authenticate user using email or phone number
        Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) 
        {
            $user = User::where('email', $request->username)
                ->orWhere('phone', $request->username)->first();
                ->orWhere('username', $request->username)->first();
            if ($user &&
                Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)
            ) {
                return $user;
            }
        });
    }
```